# How long before Ubuntu One downloads music purchases

Tags: ubuntu-one, music

How long does it take on average for a song purchased through the Ubuntu One Music store to be downloaded to my computer?

Answer (score 1):

Normally, it should happen fairly quickly. If it takes more than a few minutes then it is likely the song didn't get queued for download to the Ubuntu One server, and a support request should be filed. It may also take slightly longer during an Ubuntu release, as some servers get bandwidth throttled to make additional bandwidth available for the large number of downloads of Ubuntu that will happen during the release.